# If $\frac{d}{d t} (f(t)^2) \le 2f(t)g(t)$ then $\frac{d}{d t} \sqrt{K+f(t)^2} \le g(t)?$

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, inequality

Let $f(t), g(t)$ be a real-valued functions of $t\in(0,\infty)$ and $f(t), g(t)\ge 0$.
If $$\frac{d}{d t} (f(t)^2) \le 2f(t)g(t)$$
then how can I conclude that
$$
\frac{d}{d t} \sqrt{K+f(t)^2} \le g(t)
$$
for any $K>0$?

Comment: Work out the derivative of the left hand side of the inequality you are asked to show using the power rule and the chain rule. Then use the first inequality and you will get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If $f(t)>0$: $f'(t)\le g(t)$
2. For all $a$: $\frac{a}{\sqrt{K+a^2}}<1$

3.For $t$: $f(t)=0$ - obviously

4. For $t$: $f(t)>0$
   $$\sqrt{K+f(t)^2}'=\frac{f(t)'f(t)}{\sqrt{K+f(t)^2}}\le f'(t) \le g(t)$$